# How to prevent mouse pointer from getting in the way of keyboard-only navigation?

Tags: xorg, cursor

I prefer not to use mouse.

I do not connect it to my computer at all, but mouse pointer itself is still present in the center of desktop. Most of the time it doesn't cause any problems, since the pointer automatically disappears. But:

1. It appears every time any dropdown menu appears.
2. It hovers over anything that happens to appear under the cursor.

The second point is the most irritating: it makes impossible to use arrow keys to navigate menu, because the mouse pointer has its own opinion on what menu item should be selected.

I've seen some people suggesting to use unclutter, but as I understand it modifies window hierarchy, which is undesirable.

My current workaround is to use keynav (or temporarily plug mouse in) to move mouse pointer to the corner of desktop and hope that it won't interfere with anything there. But I would like to avoid thinking about mouse pointer movements at all.

Comment: Check this answer: [How to hide the mouse cursor](//askubuntu.com/a/586718) or the answer above it. (If you're using the standard ubuntu, look at the LightDM section).

Comment: @JonasCz, just checked it. It does hide a cursor forever, but its position still interferes with popup and dropdown menus (my p. 2 in the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no way to truly remove mouse pointer. X server requires at least one to be present.

So I ended up with using xdotool to move the cursor to bottom right corner of the desktop. I wrapped it into scrip called “nomouseplease”, which I execute upon X start:

xdotool mousemove 10000 10000